# Open a KML with MultiGeometry's in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, kml, multi-geometry

I tried to open the [Sentinel-2 tiling grid (KML 100MB)](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/1955685/S2A_OPER_GIP_TILPAR_MPC__20151209T095117_V20150622T000000_21000101T000000_B00.kml) from [ESA's website](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products) using the Data Source Manager (Vector) in QGIS 3.12. There is no error, but also the **geometries are not displayed**. The file is opened and layers appear in the layers panel:

[image: Screenshot layers panel QGIS (sentinel-2 tiling grid)]

The KML has `MultiGeometry`s, which according to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/94057/122597) cannot be opened in QGIS. How can I open the geometries found in this KML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Plugin "KML Tools" (author C Hamilton) from the official QGIS repository helped me open the KML file with MultiGeometry content.